# Converting lowercase to uppercase using 2D arrays in C

Tags: c, arrays, multidimensional-array, uppercase, lowercase

Here I want to convert some student names into uppercase using a 2D array. This compiles without an error, but at the execution it gives an error called 'segmentation fault'. I tried this using a 1D array but it only prints the last name which I've entered. At the end I want to calculate total integer value for the entered names separately. I'm fairly new to C language, so there may be so many errors. Any ideas to fix my code?

```
#include<stdio.h>

#define SIZE 6

void input(char arr[][10], int size);
void upper(char arr[][10], int size);
void findIntValue(char arr[][10], int size);

int main(void)
{
  char arr[SIZE][10] = {0.0};

  input(arr, SIZE);

  upper(arr, SIZE);

  findIntValue(arr, SIZE);

  return 0;
}

 void input(char arr[][10], int size)
{
  int i, j;

  for(i = 0 ; i < size ; i++)
 {
    printf("\nEnter the name: ");
    scanf(" %s", arr[i]);
 }
}

void upper(char arr[][10], int size)
{
  int i, j;

  for(i = 0 ; i < size && arr[i] != '\0' ; i++)
 {
    for(j = 0 ; j < 10 && arr[i][j] != '\0' ; j++)
    {
        if(arr[i][j] >= 97 && arr[i][j] <= 122)
        {
            arr[i][j] -= 32;
        }
    }
 }

 for(i = 0; i < size && arr[i] != '\0' ; i++)
 {
    for(j = 0 ; j < 10 && arr[i][j] != '\0' ; j++)
    {
        printf("\n%s\n", arr);
    }
 }
}

void findIntValue(char arr[][10], int size)
{
  int i, j;
  int total = 0;

  for(i = 0 ; i < size && arr[i] != '\0' ; i++)
 {
    for(j = 0 ; j < 10 && arr[i][j] != '\0' ; j++)
    {
        total += arr[i][j];

        printf("\n%s\t%d\n", arr, total);

        total = 0;
    }
  }
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hrZ5R.png)

Comment: `char arr[SIZE][10] = {0.0};` You initialized achar array with a `double` value.

Comment: `scanf(" %s", arr);` You should use `i` somewhere...

Comment: `for(i = 0 ; i < size && arr[i][j] != '\0' ; i++)` You use uninitialized variale `j`

Comment: This doesnot affect you program input or output. But when you defined a macro of name SIZE then dont pass an argument with name size you can directly use SIZE through out your program.

Comment: @Gerhardh if I omit 'j' in my first for loop, will it affect to the array, arr[i][j]?

Comment: @hash_hw you only need arr in the inner loop. You should remove that part of the condition completely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many problems in your code.

Problem-1: In the function input, you need to pass arr[i] as input to scanf

Problem-2:In the upper function, in the first loop, you are trying to read an uninitialized value of j which could lead to undefined behavior.

Problem-3:In the upper function, in the second loop, in the printf you are again using arr, whereas you should be using arr[i] and also, you don't need two loops for printing. One loop is enough.

Problem-4:The loop and print logic of findIntValue is wrong. You need to print the total and arr after the inner loop is completed. Also, printed value should be arr[i] and not arr.

Please find the corrected program below:

```
#include<stdio.h>

#define SIZE 6

void input(char arr[][10], int size);
void upper(char arr[][10], int size);
void findIntValue(char arr[][10], int size);

int main(void)
{
  char arr[SIZE][10] = {0.0};

  input(arr, SIZE);

  upper(arr, SIZE);

  findIntValue(arr, SIZE);

  return 0;
}

 void input(char arr[][10], int size)
{
  int i, j;

  for(i = 0 ; i < size ; i++)
 {
    printf("\nEnter the name: ");
    scanf(" %s", arr[i]);
 }
}

void upper(char arr[][10], int size)
{
  int i, j;

  for(i = 0 ; i < size && arr[i][0] != '\0' ; i++)
 {
    for(j = 0 ; j < 10 && arr[i][j] != '\0' ; j++)
    {
        if(arr[i][j] >= 97 && arr[i][j] <= 122)
        {
            arr[i][j] -= 32;
        }
    }
 }

 for(i = 0; i < size && arr[i][0] != '\0' ; i++)
 {
        printf("\n%s\n", arr[i]);
 }
}

void findIntValue(char arr[][10], int size)
{
  int i, j;
  int total = 0;

  for(i = 0 ; i < size && arr[i][0] != '\0' ; i++)
 {
    for(j = 0 ; j < 10 && arr[i][j] != '\0' ; j++)
    {
        total += arr[i][j];
    }
        printf("\n%s\t%d\n", arr[i], total);
        total = 0;
  }
}
```

Comment: `arr[i] != '\0'`doesn't make much sense in the outer loop condition

Answer (score 0):

You are using 2-d in wrong way. You need to provide `arr[i]` in `scanf()`. Because your array is a 2-d array where `arr[i]` is capable to store an string. So your input fn will contain this statement. `scanf("%s",arr[i])` same for output function. 
Hope this helps :)

Comment: still I'm getting the same error: segmentation fault :(

Comment: Dont initialize your 2d array

Comment: for(i = 0; i < size && arr[i][j] != '\0' ; i++)  in this line dont provide [j] value.

Comment: You just check wherever you are using %s there give arr[i]

Comment: I've edited my code according to your suggestion. Is that correct? If not, would you please show me the correct edition? I've removed 'j' and tried to run the code, no errors but only showing the first name I've entered, 10 times repeatedly, and not giving the correct integer values as well :(

Comment: While printing also you need to provide arr[i] in printf function like this printf("\n%s\n",arr[i])